# logon without password kubuntu 14.10

Tags: kubuntu, login, password

I just set up Kubuntu 14.10 beta, how can I set it up to not require a password when booting up (after a restart). I want to start or reboot the PC and it NOT to ask for a user name/password, just go right in.

I went to System Settings, Account Details, Clicked the "Change Passwords"
button, and I get error message:

Sorry -- System Settings
A program error occurred: the internal program 'kdepasswd' could not be found. You will not be able to change your password.

I only wish to just start up/reboot and Kubuntu Go right in ...no password required (no login)

Please advise, 
Thanks AJ

Answer (score 3):

**Unicorn**

14.10 will be released: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseSchedule

**Error**

> A program error occurred: the internal program 'kdepasswd' could not
>   be found.

Do you have the 'kdepasswd' installed ?

The 'kdepasswd' is:

```
:~$ apt-cache show kdepasswd
Package: kdepasswd
Priority: optional
...
Description: graphical password changing utility
 kdepasswd allows users to change their password, user icon, and other
 information.  A variety of user icons are included.
 .
 This package is part of the KDE base applications module.

Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Task: kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, kubuntu-active, kubuntu-active-desktop, kubuntu-active-full, kubuntu-active
```

The kdepasswd should be part of the kubuntu-desktop (at here it is).

**Passwordless login**

The passwordless login is set on from the log in screen setup.

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62639-Passwordless-login-etc-in-13-04:

> KDE System Settings > Login Screen (LightDM) > General and check
>   Automatically log in